# Define columns shown in "products in category" grid?

Tags: magento2, grid

**Magento 2.2.3**

The columns in 2.2.3 are very limited, I need the SKU and the status and maybe some more columns. Is there a way to add columns to the "products in category" grid in a category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**VendorNameSpace/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="VendorNameSpace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
</config>
```

**VendorNameSpace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorNameSpace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $grid = parent::_prepareCollection();

        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->joinTable(
            'cataloginventory_stock_status',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            ["new_attribute" => "new_attribute"],
            null ,
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToSelect('new_attribute');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        if ($this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->clear();
        }
        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn('new_attribute', ['header' => __('Stock Status'), 'index' => 'new_attribute']);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

helps this achieve your requirement. thanks

Comment: Thanks! How could I get the status (enabled/disabled) here?

Comment: How to add New column attribute and save it in to database